# how to customize color legend when using for loop

Tags: matplotlib, legend, categories, scatter-plot, colorbar

I want to draw a 3D scatter, in which the data is colored by group. Here is the data sample:

```
aa=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
                 'b':[2,3,4,5,6],
                 'c':[1,3,4,6,9],
                 'd':[0,0,1,2,3],
                 'e':['abc','sdf','ert','hgf','nhkm']})
```

Here, a, b, c are axis x, y, z. e is the text shown in the scatter. I need d to group the data and show different colors.

Here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
zdirs = aa.loc[:,'e'].__array__()
xs = aa.loc[:,'a'].__array__()
ys = aa.loc[:,'b'].__array__()
zs = aa.loc[:,'c'].__array__()
colors = aa.loc[:,'d'].__array__()
colors1=np.where(colors==0,'grey',
                 np.where(colors==1,'yellow',
                          np.where(colors==2,'green',
                                   np.where(colors==3,'pink','red'))))
for i in range(len(zdirs)): #plot each point + it's index as text above
    ax.scatter(xs[i],ys[i],zs[i],color=colors1[i])
    ax.text(xs[i],ys[i],zs[i],  '%s' % (str(zdirs[i])), size=10, zorder=1, color='k')
ax.set_xlabel('a')
ax.set_ylabel('b')
ax.set_zlabel('c')
plt.show()
```

But I do not know how to put a legend on the plot. I hope my legend is like:

[image]

The colors and the numbers should match and be ordered.

Could anyone help me with how to customize the color bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I've taken the liberty to reduce your code a bit:

- I'd suggest to create a ListedColormap to map integer->color, which allows you to pass the color column via `c=aa['d']` (note it's `c=`, not `color=`!)
- you don't need to use `__array__()` here, in the code below you can directly use `aa['a']`
- finally, you can add an empty scatter plot for each color in the ListedColormap, and this can then be rendered correctly by `ax.legend()`

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

aa=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
                 'b':[2,3,4,5,6],
                 'c':[1,3,4,6,9],
                 'd':[0,0,1,2,3],
                 'e':['abc','sdf','ert','hgf','nhkm']})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

cmap = ListedColormap(['grey', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink','red'])
ax.scatter(aa['a'],aa['b'],aa['c'],c=aa['d'],cmap=cmap)

for x,y,z,label in zip(aa['a'],aa['b'],aa['c'],aa['e']):
    ax.text(x,y,z,label,size=10,zorder=1)

# Create a legend through an *empty* scatter plot
[ax.scatter([], [], c=cmap(i), label=str(i)) for i in range(len(aa))]
ax.legend()

ax.set_xlabel('a')
ax.set_ylabel('b')
ax.set_zlabel('c')

plt.show()
```